# jquery error in IE6

Tags: jquery

my jquery code not run with IE6 but runs all others including IE7. It errors

**"JQuery is 
undefined"** .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

In to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

You should also check the charset.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call your scripts in the correct order.
`jQuery` won't be defined until it's included... by the looks of things, the browser recovers but raises it as an error.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me in IE6.  Something to do with your security settings maybe? Also try emptying your cache.